# Having problem with package tkz-euclide, some command doesn't work on overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, tkz-euclide, tkz-base

When I am trying the example from the tkz-euclide document on overleaf, I find that some of the commands are undefined, here's the example and undefined command is **\tkzDefPointOnCircle**.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,0.8/3/C}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=90,center=B,radius=1 cm]
\tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,teal](B,1cm)
\tkzDrawPoint[teal](I)
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{G} \tkzGetLength{rG}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=30,center=G,radius=\rG pt]
\tkzGetPoint{J}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle(G,J)
\tkzDrawPoint(G)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](J)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then I went online and find the command is defined in **tkz-obj-eu-points.tex** file of the tkz-euclide package. So I tried some different commands.

It turns out that all commands and environments defined in .tex file of tkz-euclide cannot be used in overleaf. Here is list, from [tkz-euclide 3.02c](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf).

☞ tkz-euclide.sty

☞ tkz-obj-eu-angles.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-arcs.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-compass.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-draw-circles.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-draw-polygons.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-points-by.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-points.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-protractor.tex

☞ tkz-obj-eu-sectors.tex

Does anyone know how to add those packages into overleaf tex environemnt?

Thank you so much for helping.

> I have include tkz-base package.
>
> And the tkz-euclide package.
>
> and I have try to add the command **\usetkzobj{all}**.

The MWE is

In .cls file

```
\LoadClass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
% Those packages are using for other purposes.
% But I am not sure if some of these will cause the issue.
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{wasysym}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Those packages are related to the problem
%\RequirePackage{tikz}    % tkz-euclide loads tkz-bse and tikz
%\RequirePackage{tkz-base} %
\RequirePackage{tkz-euclide}
```

In .tex file

```
\documentclass{blockLaTeX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Hyperbolic geometry}

\section{Belfram-Klein model}

\subsection{Interpretation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,0.8/3/C}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=90,center=B,radius=1 cm] % undefined control sequence.
\tkzGetPoint{I} % Package pgf Error: No shape named tkzPointResult is known.
\tkzDrawCircle[R,teal](B,1cm) % Package pgf keys Error.
\tkzDrawPoint[teal](I)
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{G} \tkzGetLength{rG}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=30,center=G,radius=\rG pt] % undefined control sequence.
\tkzGetPoint{J}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle(G,J)
\tkzDrawPoint(G)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](J) % Package pgf keys Error.
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: no you don't need `\usetkzobj{all}` with the version 3.02. Sorry but I can't help you with overleaf. Can you give your preamble in your question ? The list of files is not helpful. It would be better to give which macro is not defined?

Comment: Well, I tried to remove it, but it is not helping. I think it would be helpful if you could tell me a method to include .tex file into .cls file. I am using my own .cls and I don't want to make it mess.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code. If you expand to a ful MWE I'll have a look at it in overleaf for you.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you take a look, thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure, it seems that the server of Overleaf does not have those file, how do I add them my self? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem with `tkz-euclide` but with Overleaf not providing the latest version of the package.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}  % figure wont float anymore
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=29.7cm, body={18cm,25.7cm}, top=2.5cm, left=1.5cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hyperbolic geometry}

\section{Belfram-Klein model}

\subsection{Interpretation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,0.8/3/C}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=90,center=B,radius=1 cm] % undefined control sequence.
\tkzGetPoint{I} % Package pgf Error: No shape named tkzPointResult is known.
\tkzDrawCircle[R,teal](B,1cm) % Package pgf keys Error.
\tkzDrawPoint[teal](I)
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{G} \tkzGetLength{rG}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=30,center=G,radius=\rG pt] % undefined control sequence.
\tkzGetPoint{J}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle(G,J)
\tkzDrawPoint(G)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](J) % Package pgf keys Error.
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.